# detalle al guardar la fecha y hora en la base de datos de SQL desde Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vba

Buen dia a todos.

Tengo el siguiente detalle, cuando guardo la fecha y hora en la **DB** desde **VB** me los guarda de la siguiente manera: `2020-01-16 12:00:00.000` cuando en el `DateTimePicker`lo tengo de la siguiente manera: `2020-01-16 12:04:57 pm`.

Mi codigo para guardar es el siguiente:

```
 Dim fecha = New Date(DateTest.Value.Year, DateTest.Value.Month, DateTest.Value.Day)
        Dim fe As String
        fe = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        Dim Conexion As String
        Conexion = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = Conexion
        Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into Debug_Test values(" & TestID.Text & ",'" & TestUser.Text & "','" & SerialNumber.Text & "'," & Shift.Text & ",'" & fe & "','" & DebugTest.Text & "','" & FailureMode_T.Text & "','" & TestStation_T.Text & "','" & Localidad_T.Text & "','" & SubFamily_T.Text & "','" & Operador_T.Text & "','" & ErrorOperador_T.Text & "','" & Acciones_T.Text & "')", cn)
        cn.Open()
```

la ventana es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo donde se guarda la fecha y hora es de tipo **Datetime**

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pasa eso porque cuando declaras fecha y le asignas los valores de tu datetimepicker te olvidaste de cargar horas, minutos y segundos. Solo modifica la primer línea:

```
Dim fecha = DateTest.Value
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono asi como dices.

Comment: @nicolasgotting ahora el detalle es que no me guarda **am** o **pm** el formato que me guardo es el siguiente: `2020-01-16 01:21:57.000`

Comment: Internamente en SQL la fecha y la hora son almacenadas como números, deberías castear la fecha al formato que quieras. Te recomiendo que la castees desde el código, sino si querés desde sql sería algo así:
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MiCampoFecha, 100)

Comment: @nicolasgotting como se castea la fecha desde el codigo?

Comment: El datepicker tiene la propiedad format, con lo cual no deberías tener problemas. Pero si la mostras en un string hace algo como MiCampoFecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

Comment: @nicolasgotting asi esta el formato en las propiedades del `DateTimePicker`, gracias por la ayuda. Dejare que en la DB sea formato 24Hrs.